# Regular expression to add space between characters without trimming the remaining characters

Tags: regex

I want to leave space between 8 characters in a string without truncating the remaining letters.

For example:

```
var name = "mar09breallylongnamereallylongnamereallyqwe,max";
var output = name.match(/.{8}/g).join(' ');
```

This gives me an output `"mar09bre allylong namereal lylongna mereally"`.

But I need the rest of the characters too `"qwe,max`" too, so the required output should be `"mar09bre allylong namereal lylongna mereally qwe,max"`.

Can someone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than match 8, match *up to* 8:

```
name.match(/.{1,8}/g).join(' ');
```

```js
var name = "mar09breallylongnamereallylongnamereallyqwe,max";
var output = name.match(/.{1,8}/g).join(' ');
document.write(output)
```

Output:

```
mar09bre allylong namereal lylongna mereally qwe,max
```